# Runtime exception caused by android.view.InflateException while inflating the Navigation

Tags: android, androidx, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I am using androidx and am getting this error quite often but I am not able to debug the error. I am copying the necessary code and seeking help to resolve the error. I have seen other related errors and I have tried to look for erroneous xml attributes but everything seems correct.

### Error Logs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2530)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2610)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:179)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1471)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5646)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:365)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at com.khan.mymoviescenter.free.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:98)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6100)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2477)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:607)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:1512)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:104)
at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon (MenuItemImpl.java:505)
at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:585)
at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:546)
at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:128)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu (NavigationView.java:362)
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init> (NavigationView.java:228) 
at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init> (NavigationView.java:117)
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                    app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout">
            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/main" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="@string/inapp_purchases">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/buy_products"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/Buy_Products"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/navigation_item_layout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/Manage_Database">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/import_export"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_import_export_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/Import_Export"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/navigation_item_layout" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/my_database"
                android:icon="@drawable/database"
                android:title="@string/My_Database"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/search_database"
                android:icon="@drawable/searchglass"
                android:title="@string/Search_Database"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/navigation_item_layout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/Search_Online">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/search_movies"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_movies_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/Search_Movies"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/navigation_item_layout" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:id="@+id/group_settings">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/Settings" />
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/More"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/navigation_item_layout" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/Close" />

</menu>
```

### onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("My App");

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Two");
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Three"));

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    assert navigationView != null;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Can we get `MainActivity.java`

Comment: yes but its a very long file

Comment: What about just the onCreate method, or everything leading up to line 98

Comment: One of the drawables in the `main` menu is causing a problem; e.g., possibly it's not available for the Android version you're running on.

Comment: I have edited the post and pasted the onCreate() method

Comment: The issue is here: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException while loading the menu in NavigationView.

Comment: Try comment all "findViewById" except one to know which one problematic